# How to remove global component completely in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have a component called `button-widget` and it is registered globally.

```
Vue.component('button-widget', {
    template: `<button>My Button</button>`
})
```

Now, how can I delete this component permanently?

I am not talking about `v-if` or `$destroy()` -- I just want to completely remove this component in such a way that it was never defined so that for example, I get this warning: `Unknown custom element: <button-widget> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no public API to do this.

The correct solution is not to register it globally in the first place and instead just use it on a per-component basis by adding it to the `components` option of  each component you want to use it in.

Otherwise you can unregister it like this:

```vue
delete Vue.options.components['button-widget']
```

Comment: I am actually getting html and css from the server and registering the components dynamically. `Vue.component` is the only way I know of currently.